# Reporting services conditional format

Tags: reporting-services, colors, format

This is probably a easy fix for a reporting wiz:)

I want to mark a row red if it is older than current month.

Go to BackgroundColor Expression:

My expression:
=IIF(Month(Fields!Date.Value)< Today(Month()),"Red","White")

Fields.Date.Value is on the following format: (DD/MM/YYYY)

Already looked through similar posts and could not find any suitable help.

Comment: But what happens? Does it not work? Do you mean Month(Today())?

Comment: FYI - in the future you may want to look to dba.stackexchange for your SSRS questions!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that the date is less than the start of this month:

```
=iif((Fields!Date.Value < DateAdd("d", 1-Day(Today()), Today())), "Red", "White")
```